# No Access to GIT respository. How do I proceed?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, shopify

Our Shopify Plus site is under version control using GIT but we don't have access to our repository because of a legal dispute. But now the owner is wanting me to make changes to the website and I don't know the best way to proceed as I don't have a lot of GIT experience.

Can I just make changes directly to our theme files and then when (or if) we get access to our repository pull in those changes? or should I create a new repository and make my changes there and then merge the new repository into the 'existing' repository (when/if we get access to it)? Or would it be a huge mistake to just forget about the 'existing' repository and just moving forward with a new one? I'm concerned about not having access to the git comments as our site is highly customized.

Comment: You can probably do all of those, you will need to decide yourself which path you want to go down. I would not recommend editing the files directly without a safety net. If you go the route of a new repository, you might be able to merge unrelated histories, but there is no way to guarantee it can be done without merge conflicts.

Comment: When you say _but we don't have access to our repository_, what do you mean? Like you can't access (makes sense) and none of you had a clone of the repo (does _not_ make sense)?

Comment: @eftshift0 asked: **When you say but we don't have access to our repository, what do you mean?** I wasn't clear here. What I meant was we don't have a clone of the repository nor do we have access to the GitHub account containing the repository. No one internal within our company was involved in the building the website. The repository was to be transferred to our organization after final payment of the project. But because that is in a legal dispute and the owner is now wanting me to make changes to the website I don't know how exactly to proceed.

Comment: You might want to consult with your own personal lawyer, providing a bit more detail, before actually proceeding with anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is download the files as they are on the server and create an initial commit and then continue committing as you move forward with it. *eventually*, if you gain access to the original repository, you could apply either patches on the branches of the original repo or rebase the branches.... it's not like the easiest thing to do, but it's technically possible.... actually it's not *that* hard.... but you need to know what you are doing in order to pull it off..... but that's a topic for another day.